# get the value of ng-repeat repeated input elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I am generating multiple Input box like below using ng-repeat for a listing.
WIth JQuery We assign a class / unique ID and get its value. But am confused how to do the same with ng-repeat. (I am showing 50 list items in a page).

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="commentinput+[item.listing_id]" data-comment="{{item.listing_id}}" ng-model="newscopeobj+{{}}" value="" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button ng-click="validateComment(newscopeobj)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-send">
            Save
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Above code is incomplete and error code.

Rephrasing the Question: How can I get the value of each input field just above the clicked Save button (When save button is Clicked) in a angular Way.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include examples of how you've tried to use the ng-repeat?

Comment: 15 Views to this Question and 4 Answers. Wow this is why i love stackoverflow. Thank you open community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do here is to use ngModel object/array. Fixing your code it would look like this:

```
ng-model="newscopeobj[item.listing_id]"
```

In this case `newscopeobj` object will be populated with values the can be identified by corresponding `item.listing_id` key.

Also note that you don't need `value`, `id` attributes anymore, as you don't have to access DOM elements directly to read values.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/WmotdI71CD3fhM21HlAp?p=preview

Comment: Okay, How can I pass this value when Send button is clicked?

Comment: For example like this: `ng-click="validateComment(item)"`. Check the demo I included, I showed it there.

Comment: @dfsq we don't need the array  notation also. Even if the ng-model name is same, it will work because ng-repeat creates new scope for each iteration

Comment: @mohamedrias yes, of course. But I assume that OP also wants access to entire collection of values.

Comment: @dfsq In that case, Array is desirable. But OP's question doesn't mention that. OP is asking about getting that value on click of save button.  cheers :)

Comment: I forgot to use `$scope.newscopeobj = {};` in beginning of controller. I was unable to get the Item Object (listing_id & comment string). When I added `$scope.newscopeobj = {};` magically it started working.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` will create it's own isolated scope on each iteration. So you can use the same `newScope` ngmodel. In your save button just pass that as argument.

You've to make changes in three palces:

```
<input id="commentinput+[item.listing_id]"
```

must be

```
<input id="commentinput+{{item.listing_id}}"
```

Then

```
 ng-model="newscopeobj+{{}}"
```

must be

```
 ng-model="newscopeobj"
```

So your full code will be

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="commentinput+{{item.listing_id}}" data-comment="{{item.listing_id}}" ng-model="newscopeobj" value="" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button ng-click="validateComment(newscopeobj)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-send">
                            Save</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kitejuvugi/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: Plus 1 for the JSBIN Link.  But i am getting only the comment string. I want listing ID also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="commentinput+[item.listing_id]"... name="[item.listing_id]" ... >
```

In this way you'll receive all items like a array

Comment: sorry mistake - has to be name="somevarname[item.listing_id]"

Comment: lliev  The above code `id="commentinput+[item.listing_id]"` will generate unique id's for ID attribute ?

Comment: No, sorry, it seems I haven't understood the question.

Comment: The Code in your answer id="commentinput+[item.listing_id]" ,  will it generate unique id's for input ID attribute ?

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
 <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="commentinput+[item.listing_id]" data-comment="{{item.listing_id}}" ng-model="newscopeobj" value="" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button ng-click="validateComment(this.newscopeobj)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-send">
                            Save</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Changed `ng-model="newscopeobj+{{}}"` to `ng-model="newscopeobj"` in your text field and remove `value=""`

and also i have changed `ng-click="validateComment(newscopeobj)"` to `ng-click="validateComment(this.newscopeobj)"`